# Electrical socket is tripping off light

Tags: wiring

I had a builder install some lights and also an electrical socket. He used a junction box to do this from the loft lights as it was easy access. However, the hoover and hair dryer is causing this now to trip. I was wondering what may cause this and if there is a better solution.

Comment: Rohit, are you in the UK? If so, please add that tag.

Answer (score 9):

More than likely, your loft lights will be on a 5A ring, totally unsuitable for a socket. The hair-dryer & hoover are probably drawing too much and tripping it.

Get your money back from this cowboy and get a competent electrician to do the work.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a clear case of overloading a circuit. The existing loft lights were probably on a 15AMP breaker. Adding additional lights and an outlet wouldn't be so bad except for the fact that you're using the outlet for a hair dryer and a vacuum cleaner. Both those appliances are relatively heavy users of electricity and are causing the breaker to trip. Try talking to the builder and get him to fix this, put the outlet on a different circuit.

Comment: Agree 100%. However "using the hoover" is a clear tip that this is in the UK, and they don't run 15 & 20 amp breakers, they use 5 and 13 and... something else "weird" to us in the US. ;)

Comment: LOL, @FreeMan agreed. Love the terminology in different countries.   Calling a vacuum cleaner a "hoover" is the same as ppl in the US calling a facial tissue a "Kleenex".   More seriously, it would really be helpful if people would mention their location.   Even in the US, electrical codes can vary considerably.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I raise my Coke to you sir (specifically Mountain Dew) .

Comment: Thanks Harp!   I'll raise my 7-up to you as well.   I've seen the term "Cowboy" used in the UK in a derogatory manner before.  But never in the US. Cowboy culture in the US is revered.

Comment: The only reason I'd talk to this builder again is to get my money back. Everyone in the UK knows you don't put sockets on a lighting circuit, (especially if the cable is sized for 5A, which has to be assumed to be the case until proven otherwise.) I wouldn't have him work on my house again. If he's incompetent or dishonest enough to install it this way once, I wouldn't trust him to do anything right.

Answer (score 0):

Both a hair dryer and a hoover can consume 10 or 20 times the  energy that is used by (LED) lights. So it is ok for the circuit breaker to trip, if the light breaker is too weak.

But if the breaker and the wiring is made for higher loads, most likeley the GFCI did trip, which could be an indication that grounding and neutral are connected somewhere downstream the GFCI or another device in the same circuit is faulty. In this case the wiring and all connected devices should be checked for correct resistances and insulation.

Comment: In the UK (which it looks like OP is), it's extremely unlikely that there is an RCD (GFCI) on the lighting circuits.

Comment: I was under the impression that the UK required a master RCD. Would this include the lighting circuits or would this "master" be only for all the receptacle circuits? In the US we have lighting and receptacles on the same circuit, or at least it's that way in older installations.

Comment: @JimStewart Most modern installs have 'split load' consumer units over here, with everything except the lighting circuits on the RCD. I've always thought that this is so that if you have a fault, you don't have to flail around in the dark trying to locate it.

Comment: @SiHa  BS671 411.3.4 would require RCDs since a few years. Nevertheless it is recommended to distribute the lighting circuits to 2 or more RCDs in order to avoid a total light black out. This danger has been decreased anyway by the use of smart phones and laptops. I.e. since many years the probability to have more injuries or deaths from total light blackouts should be much lower than the danger from changing lamps or bulbs or from driving nails into walls or ceiling or drilling holes without any RCD for lighting circuits.